# Databaseless Laravel +Codeception - turn off database connection completely?

Tags: laravel-4, codeception

I am building an API calling app which needs no database. In trying to register a new class, I updated my composer and it updated lots of packages including Laravel (now 4.1.25). Now when I run my tests (Codeception) they break as its asking for a database connection. I can't see in the Laravel config options or looking at db connection code how to turn off database completely so it does not look for a connection.

Comment: went back to 4.1.24 and is working again... will post this as an issue.

Comment: changed db to sqlite and that seemed to work too..